# Needing to type full path to save file?

Tags: java, file, audio, save

Okay, this is my first post here, sorry if i did something wrong. (please let me know if i did aswell)

So i've been trying to make a "data" folder with a audio(.wav) file in it when the runnable jar file is run but for some reason it doesn't work, i've tried to get this working for the last week but i finally kinda gave up on trying to get it working without help(other than searching around the internet) and therefore ask here.

So i have this code:

```
public static void loop(String path, int volume) {
    try {
        if (volume > 6) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requested volume ("+volume+") is higher than allowed. (maximum 6)");
        else if (volume < -80) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requested volume ("+volume+") is lower than allowed. (minimum -80)");
        else {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path)));
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            FloatControl gain = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            gain.setValue(volume);
            clip.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for looping a .wav file continuously and it works, then i try to save the file with this code:

```
public void save(String music, String output) {
    try {
        File sound = new File(music);
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
        AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(output));
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And that seems to work aswell when i do something like this:

```
save("D:\\Eclipse\\eclipse\\workspace\\Test\\data\\music.wav", "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\data\\test.wav");
loop("C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\data\\test.wav", -30);
```

But if i try to do this instead:

```
private File jar() {
    try {
        File jar = new File(Game.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        return jar;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
private File data = new File(jar().getParentFile().getPath()+File.separator+"\\data");
private File music = new File(data.getPath()+"\\music.wav");
save(music.getPath(), "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\data\\test.wav");
loop("C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\data\\test.wav", -30);
```

it won't save the file, why is that and what can i do to make it save?

Final Notes:

1. I'm pretty new to java.
2. I'm pretty new to programming in itself.
3. I don't want to use a library, i wanna try to make it work without and i'm so close.
4. If i forgot to say anything please let me know and i'll edit this post or make a comment.

EDIT: Just wanted to make it clear that this works in the IDE but not when i export it. Also i have the data folder both IN the 'src' folder and beside the 'src' folder, just for testing.

Comment: If you just print out `jar().getParentFile().getPath()+File.separator+"\\data"` for now, instead of trying to save a file there, what path does it return? Also, what do you mean by "it won't save the file"? Is it throwing an exception, saving an empty file, or the code completes but you don't see the file where you expect to?

Comment: Printing jar().getParentFile().getPath()+File.separator+"data" while the runnable jar is on my desktop prints "C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\data", i don't see anything wrong with that. :/

Sorry, i should've explained it a little more, i meant that it doesn't show up in the folder and doesn't play the music from the folder.(because it's not there)
Also, because it's not in the IDE i don't see any console to look for errors at. :/ EDIT: How do i make the code highlighted like in your comment?

Comment: If you wrap code inside of back quotes ( ( ` ) the same key as the tilde) it will format the contained text as code. Have you validated that your program has write permissions to the 'data' folder? My hunch here, is that you're catching an `IOException` when you're calling `save(music.getPath(), "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\data\\test.wav");` which is preventing the program from crashing. Additionally, when the  exception is caught, its stack trace is printed; but it's printed to standard err; you need to define `System.err` (a stream to a log file maybe) to get the output of the stack trace.

Comment: For now though, I would try removing the try-catch from `save()`, replacing it with `throws IOException, URISyntaxException` in the method header. Regardless of where your program is running, you should get some sort of notification if you allow an exception to propagate all the way back up the stack (probably a dialog box following the crash of the program if you have this running in a UI). Hopefully the thrown exception will give you more insight into what's going wrong when `save()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the information. :) I tried making a "crash.txt" file on my desktop and print the stacktrace to it, it says `FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\Test.jar\data\music.wav` I tried putting the data folder with the music in the 'src' folder and i'm trying to get the music in the data folder from the runnable jar, is that not possible? If not then what do you recommend?

Comment: It sounds like you want to read [resource files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html#nonsys_res).

Comment: Thank you for that link. :)